# Excavator Medal not awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I'm a completionist (sorry) and I did something that I think, by definition, should have awarded me the Excavator badge (Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months) here. [Do abandoned buildings sort themselves out eventually if you just leave them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211687/do-abandoned-buildings-sort-themselves-out-eventually-if-you-just-leave-them/211693#211693)

I edited my answer from Mar-2015 to add a V2 of a plugin I suggested. The edit passed and is now shown. But the Excavator badge was not awarded. What did I not do right?

PS: The last time the post was even toutched was Dec-2015. So even if by post it meant the question and all it's answers it should be right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excavator requires you edit **someone else's post**, not your own:

> Self-edits do not count for the Excavator or Archaeologist badges. It must be an edit on another owner's (or anonymous/deleted user's) content.
>
> We don't want to encourage self-bumping of content in an attempt to get votes by bumping it on the front page for the sake of doing so...it's meant to be focused on improving old content that needs love. While this may be true for self-edits, it could also be used to exploit the badge and rep system at the same time, so we exclude that case.
> <sub>[Nick Craver - Should I have earned an “Excavator” badge for this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115018/179041)</sub>

---

Also note that some of the less-frequently awarded badges aren't updated automatically. Instead, they will be awarded at some point in the future when the update script is run. Excavator is one of those badges.

At most, you may have to wait up to 24 hours for it to appear.

Comment: So maybe this would need a rewording saying that you need to edit a post that is not yours.

Comment: Perhaps. You can raise that as a separate [feature-request] if you wish :-).